# Image animation on link hover

Tags: jquery, hover

I'm trying to implement a function (that is part of "Page" class) that animates an image on list item hover. I'm trying to achieve something like this effect: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/01/22/how-to-spice-up-your-menu-with-css3/
Here it is:

```
linkHover : function (el) {
        var $link = $.find('ul.' + el.className' li');
        var $img = el;
        console.log($img);

        $($link).hover( function() {
            $img.stop().animate({
                'left': '300px',
                'opacity': 1
            }, {duration: 'slow', queue: false});

        }, function() {
            $img.stop().animate({
                'left': '0px',
                'opacity': 0
            }, { duration: 'slow', queue: false});
        }
        );

    },
```

This throws an error when I hover the list items:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'i.stop()')
```

What can be wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: where and how are you calling linkHover  function?

Comment: $link seems to be undefined.

Comment: `$img` is not a jquery object, It should be `var $img = $(el);`

Comment: I'm calling it from another "Page's" class function, like this: `$appended = '<img src="'+src+'" class="img-flip" />';
                       $bg.append($appended); 
                       Page.linkHover($appended);` This is very awkward, but I'm not a query expert.

Comment: When `var $img = el;` console.log donne just `<img ...>`. When `var $img = $(el);`console.log donne `[<img src=...]`. When doing `var $img = $(el)[0];` console.log donne `img.img-flip`... What the right one ?

Answer (score 0):

Edit, updated

Try (this pattern)

```
   $(function() {

        var bg = $("ul li");
        var appended = $.parseHTML("<img class=img-flip />", document, false);

        var Page = {
        "linkHover" : function (el) {

           var link = $("ul li");
           var img = $(link).find(el);
           console.log(link, img);
           // if `img` has `appended` `class` 
           // attach `hover` `event` to `el` parent (`li`)
           $(img).hasClass($(el)[0].className) 

           ?

           $(link).hover( function(e) {
                $(e.target).stop().animate({
                    'left': '300px',
                    'opacity': 1
                }, {duration: 'slow'});

            }, function(e) {
                $(e.target).stop().animate({
                    'left': '0px',
                    'opacity': 0
                }, { duration: 'slow'});
            }) && alert(link[0].nodeName 
                       + "\n" + img[0].className 
                       + " hover event ready") 
            // if `img` _not_ has `appended` `class` 
            // `log` `error` messages
            : console.log(false, link, el);
            // `Page.linkHover` complete
        }};
            // append `appended` to `bg`
            // call `Page.linkHover` with
            // `appended` (`img`) parameter
             $.when($(bg).append(appended))
            .then(function(link) {
              var elem = $(link).find("img");
                alert(elem[0].nodeName + " appended");
              Page.linkHover(elem);
            }, function(link) {
              alert("error", link)
            });

    })
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/FnPpZ/

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for a newly question, but I do not understand how do I integrate it as "Page" classes's function and call it inside another "Page" function (one which add images to the DOM).

Comment: After doing some research I found that `// Code 1:
(function ($) { 
    // Javascript code 
})(jQuery)

// Code 2:
var myFunction = function ($) { 
    // Javascript code 
};
myFuntion(jQuery);` are the same things. But still do not understand how to call it from another function when its already called inside itself ?